# sapply or other apply function in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I wrote some code yesterday and it was confusing you to help. Sorry about that. So I wrote it again in an easier way.

My question is:
is there easier (or faster) way to implement the following code?

```
k <- c(.04, .08, .12, .16, .2);

library(plyr)
valfcn <- function(k, V_next){
  a <- .3;
  b <- .6;

 return_val <- vector()
  for(i in 1:5){
    tmp <- vector()
    for(j in 1:5){
  tmp[j] <- (log(k[i]^a - k[j]) + b*V_next[j]);
}
return_val <- c(return_val,max(tmp[i]))
}
  return_val

}

V0 <- c(rep(0,5))
V1 <- valfcn(k,V0)
V2 <- valfcn(k,V1)

V1
V2
```

I'd like to use alternative way which might be shorter but faster, instead of using the for-loop method.

Best!

Comment: what are your expected results

Comment: What does it mean to say: "vector in the sapply function should be added in transpose"?

Comment: Really unclear. If it is a value function iteration, it should be `sapply(1:length(k), function(i){max(log(k[i]^a - k) + b*V_next[i])})`. Is this what you mean by "vector in the sapply function should be added in transpose"?

Comment: or just `V_next[which(k %in% x)]`

Comment: Would probably help if you posted the for loop you expected this code to be equivlent to.

Comment: What does `plyr` have to do with this?

Comment: Sorry guys, I found out I "clearly" wrote down in a very "unclear" way. Let me rethink and post it more clearly.. Thank you for the comments here!

Comment: your code is effectively `log(k^a - k) + b*V_next`, and I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Should `return_val <- c(return_val,max(tmp[i]))` be `return_val <- c(return_val,max(tmp))`? It seems like you want the max of the vector rather than the max of a particular element.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `sapply()` isn't necessary based on your description. Something like this might do what you're looking for:

```
valfcn <- function(k, V_next){
  a <- .3;
  b <- .6;
  max(log(k^a - k) + b*V_next);
}
```

In this version, the transformation being done to `k` produces a vector and then `max()` operates on the **entire** vector. No need to use a loop or use `sapply()`, since `max()` takes care of it.